# ubuntu 16.04.5 boot fail, what shoud I do next?

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, vnc

I've been using ubuntu 16.04.5 for a while and this morning found my vnc terminal was stuck with a screen saver screen. I entered the machine with ssh and saw a message saying 'grub is not installed'. I briefly thought about installing grub (by sudp apt install grub), but decided to just reboot. But the system doesn't boot-up. It's just a black screen after a brief purple screen.
By pressing 'shift key' constantly (I don't know why I have to keep pressing it, when the internet says I only have to keep the shift key pressed), I can get into the grub menu, and I can see {ubuntu, memtest, memtest??}. I chose ubuntu and there I see 6 options. so I chose one (the latest, with recovery option) and after logging in, removed the 'quiet and splash' from the GRUB_DEFAULT_OPTION and ran 'sudo update-grub' and rebooted.  Now I can see the boot messages, and the final message is

```
.....
nfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=1047 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   32.804459] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
[   32.804776] igb 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: igb: enp7s0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[   32.804971] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp7s0: link becomes ready
[   36.778451] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp6s0: link is not ready
[   36.818973] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp6s0: link is not ready
```

what should I try next? I want recover only the broken point if possible. If not, I have to make a ubuntu 16.04 disk and do just a overwrite install? please tell me.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks most like an unattended update gone wrong. Try those steps first.

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```